# If in an upper bounded real sequence $X : v_m =\sup \{x_n : n \geq m\}$, then $x^* = \lim \sup X = \inf \{v_m : m \geq 1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> If  in a bounded real sequence $X : v_m =\sup \{x_n : n \geq m\}$, then :
>
> $x^* = \lim \sup X = \inf \{v_m : m \geq 1\}$

**Proof Attempt :**

If $X= \{x_n\}$ is a sequence of real numbers which is bounded above, then $\lim \sup X$ is the infimum of of those real numbers $w$ with the property that there are only a finite number of natural numbers $n$ such that $w < x_n$.

Hence, from the above definition , it's clear that $\lim \sup X$ is the greatest limit point in a upper bounded sequence $X$.

But, I am not able to understand clearly, why $x^* = \lim \sup X = \inf \{~v_m : m \geq 1\}$ where  $v_m =\sup \{~x_n : n \geq m\}$

I understand that $\inf \{~v_m : m \geq 1\}$ yields the smallest element $x_k$ of $X$ such that $x_k > x_p ~\forall~  p> k  $ . But, that does not make $x_k$ a limit point?

Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are $\lim$'s parameters ?

Comment: I am not very sure if this is what you are asking . If $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_k$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence of limit points, then $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} v_n$ is the limit supremum

Comment: You wrote $\lim\sup X$. The full way of writing something with $\lim$ would be $\displaystyle\lim_{var\rightarrow smth}\text{Expression}$. What is the variable here ? Did you mean $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup x_n$ ?

Comment: If $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_k$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence of limit points, then $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} v_n$ is the limit supremum

Comment: Hmm I'm puzzled. To me, $\lim\sup X$ would be $\sup\{v_m : m \geq 1\}$

Comment: I am sorry but are you giving a hint or asking?

Comment: I'm saying that If I had to give an answer to your question, I'd say something is wrong in the equality. However, as I may be wrong, I just posted it in the comments rather than make a full answer.